# Ruby self assign float variable with methods like .round()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have come across a very common scenario as follows-

```
var_float += 1234.1234
var_float = var_float.round(2)
```

Here the value for `var_float` is getting calculated with some complicated expressions and there I cannot do like `var_float += 1234.1234.round(2)` this. Hence one more line to reassign the same.

I was wondering if there's any better way to do this ruby?
For ex. if I can do something like `var_float .= round(2)`?

Comment: I got confused; are you trying to do `var_float += 1234.1234; var_float = var_float.round(2)`, or `var_float += 1234.1234.round(2)`? If the former, how about `var_float = (comp_expr + 1234.1234).round(2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
var_float = (var_float+1234.1234).round(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this should works for you

```
  var_float += (1234.1234.round(2))
```

Comment: Suppose `var_float = 1.234567890123456789` before your expression is executed. What's the point of rounding one operand to two digits before adding to another operand that has a far greater number of significant digits?

Comment: @CarySwoveland According to his question he need to rounding off float value while self assigning. He should be aware what he assigned initially.

Comment: The initial value of `var_float` was not necessarily assigned; it could have been the result of calculations. That's beside the point, however. The OP is looking for a shorter way of obtaining the value of `var_float` than `var_float += 1234.1234; var_float = var_float.round(2)`. Those two statements return a value rounded to two decimal places. Yours does not necessarily do so, and does not in the example I gave in my earlier comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your suggestions. i was wrong on question. keep update the people who are still learning like me :)

Comment: Another aspect is floating point inaccuracy. `(a + b).round(2)` ensures 2 decimal places, whereas `a.round(2) + b.round(2)` doesn't.